# Asp.net core post api return not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a post api in asp.net core 2.0 that return a simple message (for test ).

```
  [Produces("application/json")]
public class LoginApiController : Controller
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public LoginApiController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }


    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(_userService.GetAll());
    }


    [HttpPost("DoExam")]
    public IActionResult DoExam([FromBody] LoginViewModel login)
    {
        return Ok("Exam Done");
    }
}
```

This codes works fine in my local but when i'm upload this on server it returns 404 not found .

Am i do anything wrong ?

Here i test this api in local

PostMan Test Api:

[image: PostMan Test Api]

Comment: Can you provide the code that call this end-point?

Comment: Did other post action methods work?

Comment: No , all the post actions not work . but all the get actions work without any error

Comment: Could you also post the controller?

Answer (score 2):

The URL you used in the screenshot is not correct. It should be -

`http://localhost:14996/LoginApi`

Ideally, we do not suffix `Api` in Controller to differentiate between MVC controllers and API controllers. Instead, we name the route as `api/[controller]` so that we can all API controllers as `~/api/controllername`.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
   // POST api/login
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Post([FromBody] LoginViewModel login)
   {
      return Ok("Exam Done");
   }
}
```